# c# Query Active Directory for users who have never logged in

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to identify users who are in an Active Directory who have not logged in after so long or who have not logged in ever.

I have the code working for querying based on a login date, but I am stuck on how to find users who have never logged in.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
UserPrincipal userTmpl = new UserPrincipal(pc);
if(prmLoginDate.HasValue)
    userTmpl.AdvancedSearchFilter.LastLogonTime(prmLoginDate.Value, MatchType.LessThanOrEquals);
else
    userTmpl.LastLogon = //This is where I would like to just say 'null' or something like that;

PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(userTmpl);

foreach (Principal p in srch.FindAll())
{
    //... Do stuff here
}
```

Any help on how to do this particular search would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried passing DateTime.MinValue as prmLoginDate?

Comment: I assume you realize that `LastLogon` is the AD property `lastLogonTimestamp` and is only replicated every 14 days (by default) so you don't really know if someone logged on (for the first time) within the last 14 days. You must query every domain controller individually for the non-replicated `lastLogon` property to determine the true last logon.